# Schedule with category time not displayed correctly in toast ui calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I hope you can help me, I'm trying to use week view with  [toast ui calendar](https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar), with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var calendar = new tui.Calendar('#calendarInstructor', {
            defaultView: 'week',
            taskView: false,
            useCreationPopup: false,
            useDetailPopup: false,
            week: {
                daynames: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
                narrowWeekend: false,
                startDayOfWeek: 1
            },
        });

        calendar.createSchedules([
            {
                id: '1',
                calendarId: '1',
                title: 'my schedule',
                body: 'body',
                category: 'time',
                dueDateClass: '',
                start: new Date('2021-05-19T09:00:00'),
                end: new Date('2021-05-19T11:00:00'),
                isReadOnly: true    // schedule is read-only
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                calendarId: '1',
                title: 'second schedule',
                body: 'body',
                category: 'time',
                dueDateClass: '',
                start: new Date('2021-05-20T13:00:00'),
                end: new Date('2021-05-20T14:00:00'),
                isReadOnly: true    // schedule is read-only
            }
        ]);
```

The problem is that schedules are not placed in correct time, with wrong height, are always placed at top, and also title is not displayed.

This is how it looks:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Also can I use different time format, like a string: '2021-05-20 15:30'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests the problem is because the tui-calendar div is placed inside a bootstrap 4 tab-pane, I guess that because the tab-pane is hidden initially the tui-calendar has problems to calculate schedule position of the hidden tab.

I solved it doing this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    if (e.target) {
                        if (e.target.id == 'my-tab-id') {
                            calendar.render();
                        }
                    }
                })
```

With this when the tab is selected, renders the calendar with the createSchedules list previously added.